# How to remove the text of webkitdirectory

Tags: html, css

I added to my website a webkitdirectory input
(input type="file" id="ctrl" webkitdirectory directory multiple)

Everything is work well, but the UI of the button is very ugly.

My site is Bootstrap-based, and the new button isn't. Moreover, the text on the button ("Choose files") is not my own text (I would like to write "Choose directory").
I tryed to change this basic-design, but I just couldn't.

does anybody have any idea about that problem?

Thanks! and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to this input and customize it in css. For example you can make text on the button invisible and make :after with content. sorry for my English.

Comment: I tried, But if the text is hidden (I used "text-indent:-999px") I can't add my own text

Comment: try visibility:hidder or display-none and use :after or :before

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what are you looking for: http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/ please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: That's look pretty good, sure better than my other options. However, all the button there are "file" buttons, not "directory" buttons. Do you know directory buttons like those?

Comment: it work's well with directory buttons also, check this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/santa76/vp281j5m/ please let me know if that's you're looking for.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I looking for. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[this plug-in](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) for bootstrap make the UI of `<input type="file"/>` better.
You have only to download it, include the JS file on your pages and write an easy JQuery code in head.
There is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/4x6u8ke3/1/)